# How can I hide custom model from mytoolbox in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-desktop

I am created model in ArcGIS using model builder and python script. To build main model I have created some submodel and script in the same toolbox. I just want to show main model in the toolbox and other some model and script I want to hide so the user can not see them.

Please let me know how can achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.

Dharmesh

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting it all to python script and put the python file in a not-so-obvious location. Build a tool with the Toolbox GUI wizard and then source to the script.

This might help you get going:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Adding_a_script_tool/00150000001r000000/

Comment: You can also embed your Python script into the tool so that no one can see the scripts code, if security or proprietary knowledge/processes is concern.  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005700000017000000.htm